# enable/disabling NTP server

Tags: 12.04, ntp

Our application runs on ubuntu 12.04 precise. On this server, we have both ntpdate and ntp. How to enable and disable NTP service on-demand? I tried 'sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove/default' and 'sudo update-rc.d ntp enable/disable' commands, but when I reboot server the ntp service starts running! I suspect ntpdate starting ntp service on reboot. I removed ntpdate package from one of my experimental server- then ntp didn't start on reboot after issuing command 'update-rc.d ntp disable'.
Is there a way to control this? or is there way to permanently disable ntpdate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To stop it

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop
```

To prevent it from starting at boot

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove
```

or try

```
/sbin/chkconfig ntpd off
```

Comment: Babin, I tried update-rc.d command but still ntp server is starting on reboot. Once I removed ntpdate package from my server(experiment), then ntp is not starting on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays all the linux distributions after ubuntu14.04 use `sysctemctl`. So if you want to enable or disable ntp server use following.

```
sudo systemctl start ntp
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop ntp
```

As a system administrator I prefer you to use the following technique:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart
```